# Sticky broadcasts rebroadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-broadcast, sticky-broadcast

I want to change the extras of a sticky broadcast, does another call to sendStickyBroadcast with the same intent creates a new sticky broadcast or replaces the previous one?

Also, I use sticky broadcast to maintain a state of some property and share the state to whoever wants it (services and activities), Is there a better approach to share a state of some property between all my android classes?

Comment: Do not use system broadcasts as an in-process event bus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does another call to sendStickyBroadcast with the same intent creates a new sticky broadcast or replaces the previous one?

it replaces the current one in case that the Intent is [filter equal](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)) to the previous one that been  already broadcast

I would not use Sticky broadcast because [it been deprecated from security reasons from android 5](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendStickyBroadcast(android.content.Intent)).

also, from my experience - using sticky broadcast for the reason you describes can cause very easy to tons of bugs and unexpected behaviors if you are not considering every case the `onReceive()` can be called...

> Is there a better approach to share a state of some property between all my android classes?

yes. there are much better ways to save state across different application components, depends on the specific use case:

- save the state as a field (or object) within a singleton class.   implementing class as a singleton provide global access to it from any other application component. the singleton state will save as long as your process is alive..
- in case that you need to save the state and restore it even after the application process stops, you should save the state in one of the persistent ways to do so:   [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) is a good choice for saving persistently primitive types like strings, integers..
- storing the state with Sqlite database whould be the choice for more complex objects and lists..

Comment: thanks tal, btw, singleton is not always the answer, for example if the state of an object is time consuming to re-create and easy to maintain, it is a game changing fact that android can clean your instance and make your code re-create it when you not always expecting it (you cant really expect it as android doesnt let your app have one entry point like other OS). but if you dont mind to re-create it when needed then yeah thats a good choice. thanks again and good to hear from you again!

Comment: nice hearing from you also.. :)